# Do I need to use PrevState even if I spread the state into a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am testing some code to try and understand the `race condition` regarding the use of `setState()`.

my code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/unique-id-generator-xeq2m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

my code below:

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    id: "",
    ids: [{ id: 7 }, { id: 14 }]
  };

  // here is where I create the id numbers
  uniqueIdCreatorHandler = incrementAmount => {
    let ids = [...this.state.ids];
    let highestId = 0;
    if (ids.length > 0) {
      highestId = ids
        .map(value => {
          return value.id;
        })
        .reduce((a, b) => {
          return Math.max(a, b);
        });
    }
    let newId = highestId + incrementAmount;
    ids.push({ id: newId });
    this.setState({ ids: ids });
  };

  idDeleterHanlder = currentIndex => {
    let ids = this.state.ids;
    ids.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    this.setState({ ids: ids });
  };
  //below is when I test performing the function twice, in order to figure if the result would be a race condition
  double = (firstIncrementAmount, secondIncrementAmount) => {
    this.uniqueIdCreatorHandler(firstIncrementAmount);
    this.uniqueIdCreatorHandler(secondIncrementAmount);
  };

  render() {
    let ids = this.state.ids.map((id, index) => {
      return (
        <p onClick={() => this.idDeleterHanlder(index)} key={id.id}>
          id:{id.id}
        </p>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.uniqueIdCreatorHandler(1)}>
          Push new id
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.double(1, 2)}>Add some Ids</button>
        <p>all ids below:</p>
        {ids}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

when invoking the `double` function on the second `button` only the `secondIncrementAmount` works. You can test it by changing the argument values on the call made on the `onClick` method.

I think that I should somehow use `prevState` on `this.setState` in order to fix this.

How could I avoid this issue here? [This matter started at CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237536/safe-way-of-creating-unique-ids) but I did not realize how could I fix this.

There is also a recommendation to spread the mapped ids into `Math.max` and I could not figure out how and Why to do it. Isn't the creation of the new `array` by mapping the spreaded key values safe enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.splice` and `.push` mutate the array. Thus the current state then does not match the currently rendered version anymore. Instead, use `.slice` (or `.filter`) and `[...old, new]` for immutable stateupdates:

```
 deleteId = index => {
  this.setState(({ ids }) => ({ ids: ids.filter((id, i) => i !== index) }));
 };

 uniqueIdCreatorHandler = increment => {
   const highest = Math.max(0, ...this.state.ids.map(it => it.id ));    
   this.setState(({ ids }) => ({ ids: [...ids, { id: highest + increment }] }));
 };
```

Comment: Could you explain some things on your code, please? ```first question``` - Incredible solution. When you place ```0, ``` on ```Math.max```, how do you make this set the initial number of ```highest``` to 0? I know that it does this, but I cannot understand how.

Comment: ```second question``` - once you set the ```state``` on ```uniqueIdCreatorHandler``` ```({ ids }) =>``` ```ids``` is the ```prevState```, correct?

Comment: ```third question``` - ```({ ids: [...ids, { id: highest + increment }] }));
 };``` - on this part when you spread ```...ids``` inside this array, you are referring to the arg ```ids```, which I have asked on the ```second question``` if it is the equivalent to ```prevState```? How come inside the ```array``` you spread the ```...ids```, then separate the new ```state``` from it with a ```coma```? I did not understand this ```sintax```. Could you please explain it to me ?

Comment: Oh I guess that ```ids``` on my second and third questions refer to ```this.state.ids```, right? But I still cannot understand this syntax on the ```setState```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` can be asynchronous, batching up multiple changes and then applying them all at once. So when you spread the state you might be spreading an old version of the state and throwing out a change that should have happened.

The function version of setState avoids this. React guarantees that you will be passed in the most recent state, even if there's some other state update that you didn't know about. And then you can product the new state based on that.

> There is also a recommendation to spread the mapped ids into Math.max and I could not figure out how and Why to do it

That's just to simplify the code for finding the max. Math.max can be passed an abitrary number of arguments, rather than just two at a time, so you don't need to use reduce to get the maximum of an array.

```
uniqueIdCreatorHandler = incrementAmount => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let ids = [...prevState.ids];
    let highestId = Math.max(...ids.map(value => value.id));
    let newId = highestId + incrementAmount;
    ids.push({ id: newId });
    this.setState({ ids: ids });    
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining regarding the ```Math.max``` related question. Now regarding the use of ```prevState``` in oder to avoid not getting the first ```setState```forgotten, isn't this happening here once we call ```double``` on clicking that second button? Shouldn't the ```state``` change twice there, incrementing by 1, then by 2? Once we  invoke the ```double``` function it clearly noticed that the first ```setState``` is forgotten, as on the ```secondIncrementAmount``` arg is considered. What would be the solution for that? And isn't this effect the presence of a ```race condition```?

Comment: Yes, the bug happens in `double`. It increments by 1, but then when it tries to increment by 2 it throws out what it did to increment by 1. With my code, it should increment by 1, and then increment by an additional 2 (keeping the first increment of 1). `isn't this effect the presence of a race condition`. I tend to save the term "race condition" for cases where the behavior is nondeterministic: it sometimes happens in one order, and sometimes in a different order. This code may be counterintuitive, but it's also deterministic.

Comment: I have changed a slight detail on your code to avoid having the result as being ```infinity``` if ```ids.length === 0```:  ```let highestId = 0;
      if (ids.length > 0) {
         highestId = Math.max(...ids.map(value => value.id));
      }```. I have used your code and once invoking ```double``` I still see only the ```secondIncrementAmount``` arg being rendered, or in other words, only the second call of the ```uniqueIdCreatorHandler``` ```method``` is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant solution but you can pass a callback to setState(see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

If you modify `uniqueIdCreatorHandler` like this:

```
uniqueIdCreatorHandler = (incrementAmount, next) => {
  let ids = [...this.state.ids];
  let highestId = 0;
  if (ids.length > 0) {
    highestId = ids
      .map(value => {
        return value.id;
      })
      .reduce((a, b) => {
         return Math.max(a, b);
    });
  }
  let newId = highestId + incrementAmount;
  ids.push({ id: newId });
  this.setState({ ids: ids }, next); //next will be called once the setState is finished
};
```

You can call it inside double like this.

```
double = (firstIncrementAmount, secondIncrementAmount) => {
  this.uniqueIdCreatorHandler(
    firstIncrementAmount,
    () => this.uniqueIdCreatorHandler(secondIncrementAmount)
  );
};
```